# Google Plus Domain Api Access For Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to integrate Google Plus and Google Plus Domain API In my android application.

I have integrated Google Plus API using Google Plus Services. It was quiet simple steps.

Now i want to fetch List of Circles by user. So i guess i need to use Google Plus Domain API . However I can not see any methods or class to Fetch Circles of user using Google Play services.

So i Goggled and found these libraries to call Google Plus Domain API.
Libraries are in this link https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup

As i have authenticated user from Google Play services , how to create object of PlusDomain to get List of Circles by User
Code example by Google 
https://developers.google.com/+/domains/circles/listing

```
    PlusDomains.Circles.List listCircles = plusDomains.circles().list("me");
listCircles.setMaxResults(5L);
CircleFeed circleFeed = listCircles.execute();
List<Circle> circles = circleFeed.getItems();

// Loop until no additional pages of results are available.
while (circles != null) {
  for (Circle circle : circles) {
    System.out.println(circle.getDisplayName());
  }

  // When the next page token is null, there are no additional pages of
  // results. If this is the case, break.
  if (circleFeed.getNextPageToken() != null) {
    // Prepare the next page of results
    listCircles.setPageToken(circleFeed.getNextPageToken());

    // Execute and process the next page request
    circleFeed = listCircles.execute();
    circles = circleFeed.getItems();
  } else {
    circles = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: FYI the Domains API will not work for Gmail accounts.

Comment: Question is want to fetch circles of user.. And then people inside circles.. How to do that in android

Answer (score 0):

"Domain API will work only with domain email id".

Now that the base is clear, [here](https://github.com/rohantan/GooglePlusMini) is the solution for your question. I know I am replying to this post very late, but I hope it will be helpful to others looking for the solution.

Steps:

1. Use GoogleAuthUtil to get Access token for the accountName (which is domain email address)

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html

```
 String scope = “oauth2:”+ ”<profile scope>”+”<circles scope>”+.....maybe more...
// Replace <> part with scope URLs from Google Domain API scopes page
 String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, accountName , scope);
```

2.Initialize GoogleCredential with Access token and Initialize PlusDomain API Client with the credential from Step1.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken( token );
    PlusDomains plusDomains = new PlusDomains.Builder(new NetHttpTransport, new
            JacksonFactory, credential ).build();

//Example of retrieving profile

Person mePerson = plusDomains.people().get("me").execute();

//Retrieve circles, people
```

Note that SCOPE is very important, make sure you are providing appropriate scopes.